# Как сделать автоматическое закрытие заказов спустя 20 дней?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php7.4

```
    <?php


namespace app\controllers;


use app\models\admin\Markettrans;
use app\models\admin\Order;
use app\models\User;
use Cassandra\Date;

class MessagesController extends AppController
{
    public function indexAction(){
        $this->setMeta('Заявки');
    }

    public function emailAction(){
        if(!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['tel-code'])){
            $sub = 'Скидка 5%, рассылка';
            $mes = 'Скидка 5%, рассылка';

            \R::exec("INSERT INTO `messages`(`subject`, `message`, `fromtel`, `name`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [
                $sub, $mes, $_POST['tel-code'], $_POST['name']
            ]);

            $_SESSION['mailsuccesssend'] = "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена.";
            //ajaxReturnIf(true, 100, ['message' => "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена."]);
        }

        redirect();
        //ajaxReturnIf(true, 200, ['message' => "Не корректные данные."]);
    }


    public function coopAction(){
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            if ($_POST['type']=='drop') {
                if(\R::exec("INSERT INTO `coop`(`type`, `shopname`, `typeshop`, `links`, `countday`, `fio`, `boss`, `email`, `tel`) VALUES ('drop','{$_POST['shopname']}','{$_POST['typeshop']}','{$_POST['links']}','{$_POST['countday']}','{$_POST['fio']}','{$_POST['boss']}','{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['tel']}')")){
                    $_SESSION['mailsuccesssend'] = "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена.";}
                redirect();
            } else
                if ($_POST['type']=='opt') {
                    if(\R::exec("INSERT INTO `coop`(`type`, `shopname`, `typeshop`, `links`, `catinfo`, `fio`, `boss`, `email`, `tel`) VALUES ('opt','{$_POST['shopname']}','{$_POST['typeshop']}','{$_POST['links']}','{$_POST['catinfo']}','{$_POST['fio']}','{$_POST['boss']}','{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['tel']}')")){
                        $_SESSION['mailsuccesssend'] = "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена.";}
                    redirect();
                } else
                    if ($_POST['type']=='market') {
                        if(\R::exec("INSERT INTO `coop`(`type`, `shopname`, `ifshop`, `sitelink`, `typeshop`, `about`,`fio`, `boss`, `email`, `tel`,`countday`,`xml`,`xmllink`) VALUES ('market','{$_POST['shopname']}','{$_POST['ifshop']}','{$_POST['sitelink']}','{$_POST['typeshop']}','{$_POST['about']}','{$_POST['fio']}','{$_POST['boss']}','{$_POST['email']}','{$_POST['tel']}','{$_POST['countday']}','{$_POST['xml']}','{$_POST['xmllink']}')")){
                            $_SESSION['mailsuccesssend'] = "Ваша заявка успешно отправлена.";}
                        redirect();
                    } else
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Сообщение не отправлено. Напишите нам, или позвоните.";
            redirect();
        }
    }


    public function orderSuccessAction()
    {
        $date = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Kiev'));
        $currentHour = $date->format("H");

        if ($currentHour < 11 || $currentHour > 18) {
            echo "Разсылка напоминаний возможна с 11:00 до 18:00";
            die();
        }

        $currentDate = $date->format("Y.m.d H:i:s");
        $date->modify('-3 hour');
        $modifyDate = $date->format("Y.m.d H:i:s");

        $orders = \R::getAll("
            SELECT `order`.*, `user`.`chatbotid` 
            FROM `order` 
            JOIN `user` ON `user`.`brand` = `order`.`brand` AND `user`.`chatbotid` != '0'
            WHERE `order`.`status` = 'new' AND `confirmed` != '1'  AND `order`.`multybrand` IS NULL AND `order`.`update_at` < '{$modifyDate}'
            GROUP BY `order`.`id`
        ");

        if ($orders) {
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                telegramSendMessage($order['chatbotid'], 'Обработайте заказ №'. $order['id'] .' в срочном порядке!');
            }

            $ids = implode("', '", array_column($orders, 'id'));
            \R::exec("UPDATE `order` SET `update_at`='{$currentDate}' WHERE `id` IN('{$ids}')");
        }

        echo "Напоминания отправленые!";
        die();
    }


    public function pendingOrderAction()
    {
        $date = new \DateTime(null, new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Kiev'));
        $date->modify('-1 week');
        $modifyDate = $date->format("Y.m.d 23:59:59");

        $orders = \R::getAll("
            SELECT `order`.*, `user`.`chatbotid`, `user`.`balance`, `user`.`grayzone`, `user`.`id` AS `user_id`,
                   `promo`.`size` AS `promo_size`, `promo`.`name` AS `promo_name`, `brand`.`commission`
            FROM `order` 
            JOIN `user` ON `user`.`brand` = `order`.`brand`
            LEFT JOIN `promo` ON `promo`.`id` = `order`.`promocode`
            LEFT JOIN `brand` ON `brand`.`title` = `order`.`brand`
            WHERE `order`.`status` IN('new', 'wait') AND `order`.`multybrand` IS NULL AND `order`.`date` < ? AND `user`.`brand` = 'BEZET'
            GROUP BY `order`.`id`
        ", [$modifyDate]);

        if ($orders) {
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                $orderDate = new \DateTime($order['date'], new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Kiev'));
                $orderDate = $orderDate->format("Y.m.d");

                $modifyDate = $date->format("Y.m.d");
                if ($orderDate === $modifyDate) {
                    telegramSendMessage($order['chatbotid'], "Обработайте заказ № {$order['id']} в срочном порядке! Иначе он будет переведен в статус \"Выполнен\" автоматически!");
                    continue;
                }
                // The same conditions ? 
                $date->modify('-1 week');
                $modifyDate = $date->format("Y.m.d");
                if ($orderDate === $modifyDate) {
                    telegramSendMessage($order['chatbotid'], "Обработайте заказ № {$order['id']} в срочном порядке! Иначе он будет переведен в статус \"Выполнен\" автоматически!");
                    continue;
                }
                
               /* 
                if($orderDate == '-20 days'){
                    telegramSendMessage($order['chatbotid'], "Заказ № {$order['id']} переведен в статус \"Закрыто\"");
                    \R::exec("UPDATE `order` SET `status` = 'close' WHERE `id` = ? ", [$order['id']]);
                }*/

                $date->modify('-1 week');
                $modifyDate = $date->format("Y.m.d");
                if ($orderDate <= $modifyDate) {
                    $commission = $order['commission'] / 100;
                    if (! empty($order['promo_size']) && $order['promo_name'] !== '1+1=3') {
                        $commission -= $order['promo_size'] / 100;
                    }
                    $sumOrderProduct = \R::getCell("SELECT SUM(`price`) FROM `order_product` WHERE `order_id` = ?", [$order['id']]);
                    $resultSum = (int)($sumOrderProduct * $commission);

                    $oldBalance = $order['balance'];
                    $oldGrayZone = $order['grayzone'];
                    $order['grayzone'] += $resultSum;

                    $marketTrans = \R::take('markettrans');
                    $marketTrans->user_id = $order['user_id'];
                    $marketTrans->comment = "Списание средств за заказ № ". $order['id'];
                    $marketTrans->sum = $resultSum;
                    $marketTrans->status= 'Успешно';
                    $marketTrans->pay = '1';
                    $marketTrans->beforetrans = $oldBalance;
                    $marketTrans->aftertrans = $order['balance'];
                    $marketTrans->oldgrayzone = $oldGrayZone;
                    $marketTrans->newgrayzone = $order['grayzone'];

                    \R::exec("UPDATE `order` SET `status` = 'success' WHERE `id` = ? ", [$order['id']]);
                    \R::store($marketTrans);
                    \R::exec("UPDATE `user` SET `balance` = '{$order['balance']}', `grayzone` = '{$order['grayzone']}' WHERE `id` = ?", [$order['user_id']]);
                }
            }
        }

        echo "Напоминания отправленые! Заказы обработаны!";
        die();
    }

}
```

Вот код.

Comment: удобно, наверное, писать код в одну длиииинную строку, чтобы потом скроллить его постоянно

Comment: @teran можно поставить три монитора в ряд :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускайте программу (точнее скрипт `php`) по **[CRON'у](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)**, в котором будет прописана выборка из бд, и выбор элементов, которые больше 20 дней и их обнуление. cron можно настроить на различные интервалы, в т.ч. на запуск скрипта каждый день.